# No nonzero continuous linear functional on $C([0,1])$ with this metric

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $V \subset C([0,1])$ be a topological vector space. Let $d(f,g) = \int_0^1 \sqrt{\vert f - g \vert}dx$. Prove that there do not exist any nonzero continuous linear functionals on $V$. My first thought was to prove that any continuous linear functional must be zero on polynomials, and then extend to all of $V$ by density, but I'm struggling to do even this. Any hints or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you assume that $V$ contains the polynomials? (If so I guess $V$ is not assumed to be closed right?)

Comment: Without further assumptions the claim is false, choose any $f\in C[0,1]$ non-trivial and let $V = span(f)$. Then define $\varphi(cf) = c$. This is a non-trivial continuous linear functional (because $c_n\rightarrow 0$ if and only if $\sqrt{|c_n|}\rightarrow 0$).

Comment: @Yanko there are no other assumptions placed on $V$. I guess the problem is simply incorrect as stated. What assumptions would need to be placed for the statement to be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated the assertion is trivially false because $V$ could be finite-dimensional, and the dual of a finite-dimensional TVS agrees with the algebraic dual and it has the same dimension as $V$.

The well-known result (proof at the end) is that if $V$ contains a non-empty convex and open set, then $V=C[0,1]$. And this implies that the dual of $V$ is zero. Because if $\phi\in V^*$, then $\phi^{-1}(B_1(0))$ is nonempty, convex, and open. Hence $\phi^{-1}(B_1(0))=V$, and so $\phi=0$.

---

**Lemma.** If $V_0\subset C[0,1]$ is nonempty, convex, and open, then $V_0=C[0,1]$.

*Proof.* Since open sets can be translated, we may assume without loss of generality that $0\in V_0$. As $V_0$ is open, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta(0)\subset V_0$. Fix $f\in V$. Choose $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n^{-1/2}\,d(f,0)<\delta$. The function
$$
s\longmapsto \int_0^s |f|^{1/2}
$$
is continuous with range $[0,d(f,0)]$. This allows us to choose, for each $k=1,\ldots,n$, numbers $s_k$ such that
$$
\int_0^{s_k}|f|^{1/2}=\frac kn\,d(f,0).
$$
Now let $\{h_k\}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to the intervals $\{[s_{k-1},s_k]$ and define
$$
g_k(t)=n\,f(t)\,h_k(t).
$$
Then $g_k\in C[0,1]$ and
$$
d(g_k,0)=\int_0^1n^{1/2}\,|f|^{1/2}\,h_k^{1/2}\leq \int_0^{s_k}n^{1/2}\,|f|^{1/2}=n^{1/2}\,\frac{d(f,0)}n=n^{-1/2}\,d(f,0)<\delta.
$$
This tells us that $g_k\in B_\delta(0)\subset V_0$ for all $k$. We can write
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n\,g_k=\sum_{k=1}^nf\,h_k=f\,\sum_{k=1}^nh_k=f.
$$
So $f$ is a convex combination of the $g_k$, and thus $f\in V$. So $V=C[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh I see, I hadn't known this lemma before. Thanks!